# name of chapter in separate line from number of chapter in title of chapters

Tags: chapters, titlesec, fmtcount

What do I want:

```
chapter one 
introduction
```

What I have already:

```
chapter one introduction
```

Code I used:

```
\begin{document}

\newpage
\renewcommand*\contentsname{List of Content}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Content}
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{Introduction}
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \input{chapters/introduction}
%   \newpage
    \renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
    \bibliographystyle{myunsrt}
    \bibliography{../allReferences} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Your  question says that you want **this** but you have **this**. I do not understand what you want, presumably **that** but you don't show **that**.

Comment: i want number of chapter EX(chapter one) in line and the name of chapter Ex. (introduction) in new line... now displayed all the number of chapter and name of chapter in one line Ex. (chapter one introduction)

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want:

```
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\usepaclage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\huge\filright}{\chaptername \Numberstring{chapter}}{2ex}{}
```

Of course, adjust the font size and the vertical spacing added to your needs.

If you have unnumbered chapters, you'll need to add a different format for them, using the default `hang` style:

```
\titleformat{name=\chapter, numberless}{\huge\filright}{}{0ex}{}
```

Comment: wrong with first line "Argument of \ttl@format@ii has an extra }. ...ght}{\chaptername \Numberstring{chapter}}}" @Bernard

Comment: i want name of the number chapter such as: (chapter one) not (chapter 1)

Comment: Yes , I didn't check the braces. I've fixed it. This being said, with `\chaptername \Numberstring{chapter}` you do obtain `chapter One`. You even can have the very oldstyle `chapter the First` with `\Ordinalstring{chapter}`.

Comment: i'm so sorry @Bernard...\titleformat{name=\chapter, numberless}{\huge\filright}{\chaptername \Numberstring{chapter}}{0ex}{} but the result (chapter 1 introduction) i want (introduction) in second line

Comment: The numberless version has an empty third argument. I was not clear enough, I think: you need both  the first  version, in `[display]` style for the numbered chapters, and the second version for unnumbered chapters (bibliography, index, table of contents and so on). Both have to be in your preamble, unless you have no unnumbered chapters.

Comment: i wrote 2 lines first and second but the result does not change all the title in one line. i want number of chapter EX(chapter one) in line and the name of chapter Ex. (introduction) in new line

Comment: Please post a small compilable example reproducing the problem. Maybe some package you load inhibits  this code.